# Commands API not working correctly in Macs - possible Chrome bug?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to register a command to use with my extension. Following the documentation present [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands), I added this to the manifest:

```
       {
        "name": "My extension",
        ...
        "commands": {
          "toggle-feature-foo": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
            },
            "description": "Toggle feature foo"
          }
        },
        ...
      }
```

When I load the extension in Windows Chrome, everything works as it should, but when I load it on a Mac, the shortcut itself (Command+Shift+Y) is not registered but the description is. It will show the description - *Toggle feature foo* - with no shortcut.

While testing this, there were no other extensions installed. I tested it on 2 Mac with the same result. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=657985&can=4&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that this key combination (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) is [*already* used by OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2010/01/18/immediately-create-a-new-stickies-note-with-shift-command-y/) as a system-wide shortcut - and therefore cannot be overridden by Chrome.

Comment: I've tried other combinations without success. eg. cmd + shift + s
I can add it manually via the commands menu in Chrome